# Setting a default view on Apex Classes

Tags: administration, ui

Is there any mechanism to set the default view on this screen?

[image: Apex Classes]

Answer (score 1):

My observation has been that it remembers the last view that was used. I don't believe a default can be set.

Comment: I had a reason to believe this is how it worked, but it seems to be defaulting to one particular view every time. I am the system administrator on this org and so I am not sure why it wont' keep the last view I used.

Answer (score 0):

What I personally keep is a view without any namespace which makes sure that I am able to see my apex classes. Create view and keep the namespace field as blank.
Once I have made my managed package then I make the view with my namespace.

Hope this helps for you.

Comment: I have already created the view I want. Now I need it to default to that view each time. Your suggestion tells me on how to create a view. I don't find that useful in the context of my question.

Comment: Can you make that view "Only visible to me" and check.

Comment: Are you referring to the ``"Step 4. Restrict Visibility"`` option? I have set it to ``"Visible only to me"``

Comment: I just checked, Salesforce is navigating to my view. I can't remember I making any other setting. But all I have are two views one is All and one is my view.

Comment: I have a total of 6 views and it is defaulting to one that I don't want it to.

Comment: I think what I did now is, edited the "All" view to "View one",  created "View two" and w "View Three" and created one more view "AAA", it is always landing me to "View one". The one view that salesforce gives bydefault.

Comment: The Apex Classes page is broken that way. It does not remember a view. Instead, it always goes for the first view it can find, by created date, if I recall correctly. Either the underlying Visualforce page doesn't save/load the data, or there's nowhere *to* save the data (e.g. as opposed to a regular object). Also, while we're on the subject of bugs: I've managed to get a View State Exceeded error during compilation by accidentally breaking a "god class." It tries to remember all the errors it encounters, and so ends up crashing if you exceed the limit.